# Not Greedy algorithm for Set Cover

Tags: algorithm, set, cover

Details about my sets:
each set have exactly **M** elements, and each element belongs to exactly **N** sets.

I need a **Non greedy** algorithm to compute the size of the minimal set cover.

is there a good algorithm? (for my special case)

thanks.

Comment: When you say "good", do you mean an efficient one? Why do you require it to be non-greedy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardness results and probably the inapproximability results (perhaps with a worse constant) apply even to your special case. Use a solver for mixed-integer programs such as [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/s/glpk/).